# how to change the colour of uitableviewcell on the basis of flags coming from server

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am making an inboxmodule in which i am using table view and my tableview data is coming from server i am stuck with it that i want to change tablecell colour on the basis of flag coming from server if messagereadflag=0 then i want grey colour of cell and if message read flag =1 then i want clear colour so that user will easily differentiate between read and unread messages. how it can be done when flags are coming from server below is my response

```
-(void)inboxmessagesGetSuccess:(FBGenericWebHandler*)handler response:(NSDictionary*)response
{
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

    NSMutableArray *inboxArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *firstarray=[[[response objectForKey:@"messageResponse"] objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"messages"];
    for(NSDictionary *tmp in firstarray)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *messages=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [messages setValue:[tmp objectForKey:@"messageId"] forKey:@"messageId"];
        [messages setValue:[tmp objectForKey:@"messageDate"] forKey:@"messageDate"];
        [messages setValue:[tmp objectForKey:@"messageTime"] forKey:@"messageTime"];
        [messages setValue:[tmp objectForKey:@"offerTitle"] forKey:@"offerTitle"];
        [messages setValue:[tmp objectForKey:@"messageRead"] forKey:@"messageRead"];// here are coming flags
        [self.inboxmessagesarray addObject:messages];
    }
    [self.tb reloadData];
    }
```

and below is my tableview cell code:

```
  -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *tableviewidentifier = @"cell";
    tablecellTableViewCell *cell= [self.activitiesTableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[tablecellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
    }if(indexPath.row == [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1){

    }

    UILabel *valuedate = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:21];
    UILabel *msg = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:22];
    UILabel *date = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:23];
    UILabel *time = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:24];
    if([[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"messageRead"] intValue]==0)
    {
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    }
    valuedate.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"offerTitle"];
    msg.text=@"How are you?";
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        NSString *img=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"offerPhoto"];// here i am getting image path
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:img];
        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //in main thread update the image
            cell.imageView.image = image;
            cell.textLabel.text = @""; //add this update will reflect the changes
        });
    });



    date.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"messageDate"];
    time.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"messageTime"];


    return cell;
    }
```

thanx in advance kindly help :(

Comment: make a dictionary of tags as key and color object as value then after getting tag from server fetch color object from dictionary as tag key.

Comment: i could not understand it will you provide any sample example for it ?

Comment: you are the same whom i answer before that checkbox count?

Comment: yes i am doing on the same project

Comment: i had mentioned in question already

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66626/discussion-between-johny-kumar-and-mishal-awan).

Comment: use this property       cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];

Comment: @MishalAwan for the sake of knowledge why don't you create a Model class named InboxMessage and initialize it with the NSDictionary coming from the server and use that object every instead of using NSDictionary. That will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **cell.contentView.backgroundColor** instead of **cell.backgroundcolor** property.

Try with this code in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method

```
if([[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"messageRead"] intValue]==0)
{
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
}
else
{
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Or use **willDisplayCell** method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        if([[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"messageRead"] intValue]==0)
    {
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    }

}
```

Comment: i want also change colour on btn click as well but on btn click i am also setting content view but then thi gray colour is not showing ?

Answer (score 2):

Use UITableView delegate method to update cell,

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if([[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"messageRead"] intValue]==0)
    {
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add condition in

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
```

That checks flag value.

```
    if([[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"messageRead"] intValue]==0)
    {
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    }
```

Comment: -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{    before return cell;

Comment: k wait i will let u tell

Comment: i added but nothing happens

Comment: you are having lots of labels in this cell. so they must be clear color background to check  this, as if they are having background color than you can not see whats background color of cell

Comment: i have updated my question with ur given code kindly have a look on it

Comment: yes. just try to apply background color to msg label. than  you can check it for temp.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66627/discussion-between-mishal-awan-and-hardik-hadwani).